# Jest - Unknow "preset" - "jest-react-native"

Tags: react-native, jestjs, babel-jest

I'm using the following package.json (according to http://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/tutorial-react-native.html#content):

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start",
    "test": "jest",
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^15.3.1",
    "react-native": "0.31.0",
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-jest": "^14.1.0",
    "babel-preset-react-native": "^1.9.0",
    "jest": "^14.1.0",
    "jest-cli": "^13.1.0",
    "jest-react-native": "^14.1.3",
    "react-test-renderer": "^15.3.1"
  },
  "jest": {
    "globals": {
      "__DEV__": true,
      "__RCTProfileIsProfiling": false
    },
    "preset": "jest-react-native"
  }
}
```

But I get the error:

```
Error: Unknown config option "preset" with value "jest-react-native". This is either a typing error or another user mistake and fixing it will remove this message.
Using Jest CLI v13.2.3, jasmine2, babel-jest
 FAIL  __tests__/AuthorRequest-test.js (0s)
● Runtime Error
  - Error: Cannot find module 'throwOnWrongReactAPI' from 'react-native.js'
        at Resolver.resolveModule (node_modules/jest-cli/node_modules/jest-resolve/build/index.js:197:17)
        at eval (node_modules/react-native/Libraries/react-native/react-native.js:180:26)
        at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/react-native/Libraries/react-native/react-native.js:189:4)
1 test suite failed, 0 tests passed (0 total in 1 test suite, run time 2.238s)
npm ERR! Test failed.  See above for more details.
```

my .babelrc file contains:

```
{
  "presets": ["react-native"]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a feeling that you are using a wrong version of Jest. You have:

```
"jest": "^14.1.0",
"jest-cli": "^13.1.0"
```

But it seems you have `13.2.3`installed using `npm -g`:

```
Using Jest CLI v13.2.3, jasmine2, babel-jest
```

First of all, I think you can remove `jest-cli` and just use `jest 14.1.0`.

Then you can update your `test` script like:

```
"scripts": {
  "test": "./node_modules/jest/bin/jest.js"
}
```

In this way,  you make sure you run the local Jest copy of your project, so it should say now:

```
Using Jest CLI v14.1.0, jasmine2, babel-jest
```

Doing that and following the official [docs](http://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/tutorial-react-native.html#content) you posted, it should be everything you need (Can't say for sure since you did not post the test code).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It seemed jest was installed in my cache or something.. I updated to this: 

"babel-jest": "*",
    "babel-preset-react-native": "^1.9.0",
    "jest-cli": "*",
    "jest-react-native": "*",
    "react-test-renderer": "*"

and 

  "jest": {
    "globals": {
      "__DEV__": true
    },
    "preset": "jest-react-native",
    "modulePathIgnorePatterns": [
      "fbjs",
      "core-js"
    ]
  }

with the following scripts:
"clean-all": "rm -rf node_modules/; rm -f tsconfig.json; npm cache clean; npm install;"

Comment: By the way, https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/troubleshooting.html#caching-issues. So you could have also tried `jest --no-cache`.